# Symfony view transfomer. ReverseTransform not being called

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to build a customer form field.  It's a date picker  but I am having trouble with my view data transformer.  Forget about the date picker stuff, I have it down to a bare bones example.  This just displays and accepts date. A simplified version of the Symfony date type.

I have this type in a bundle.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateToStringTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MyDateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new DateToStringTransformer());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mydate';
    }
}
```

Here's my transformer.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class DateToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return '';
        }

        if (!$value instanceof \DateTime) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a \DateTime.');
        }

        return $value->format('n/j/Y');
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a string.');
        }

        return \DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', $value);
    }
}
```

Service is defined like this:

```
mydate:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\MyDateType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: mydate}
```

In AppBundle/Resources/Views/form.html.twig.

```
{% block mydate_widget %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endblock %}
```

In config.yml

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

And in a controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/test2")
 */
public function test2Action(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder([
        'date' => \DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '11/20/2014')
    ])
        ->add('date', 'mydate')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
        ;

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    }

    return $this->render('default/test2.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

The transformer works from date to string. Its transform method is called and the date displays nicely as expected. But reverseTransform is not called when the form is posted.

I feel like I'm missing something that tells it where the posted value comes from. It should of course be the posted value of the input element but I don't quite see how that happens automatically.

Do I need a model transformer? I don't think so because my "model data" and "norm data" are both DateTime.  I only need to convert to a string for the view.

Comment: I've been having the same problem using symfony 3, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Duh! Just found it.

In MyDateType I need

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'compound' => false
]);
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer and not just a "solved it". Finally found the answer I was looking for :D